# How to speed wordpress disqus plugin loading?

Tags: disqus

When I'm testing my blog page loading time in pingdom tools and webpagetest.org, both of these services display disqus plugin takes 5-10 seconds to load. Are there any way to speedup its page loading time?

Are there any way to load disqus only if the visitor only need to comment or view the comments?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the comments until click are two possible solutions:

http://www.paulund.co.uk/ajax-disqus-comment-system

http://blog.yjl.im/2012/04/let-your-readers-decide-when-to-load.html

http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472097-universal-embed-code

Comment: Thank you LPH. I have one question. To where i should place that HTML and Jquery codes? I can't find that information in that tutorial. If i should place it theme where's the appropriate area (eg:- before <\body>). I use Genesis premium theme one of its child theme.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a few more links. Maybe this will help.